# Values not being added to SQLite Database through Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-2.7

I'm using Python to create a registration system that adds values into an SQLite database. With my code I don't get any errors when ran but the data isn't added into the table.

```
import sqlite3 as db #Import the SQLite module as db
import smtplib as mail #Importing the send email library as mail
from email.mime.text import MIMEText #Importing the text component of the mail library


#Getting the user to input the their data
username = raw_input("What would you like your username to be? ")
email = raw_input("What is your email address? ")
firstName = raw_input("What is your first name? ")
surname = raw_input("What is your surname? ")
age = raw_input("How old are you? ")
password = raw_input("What is your password?") #Encryption method will be added later
int(age) #Changing the age variable into an integer so it can be inputted into the database

#DB part
conn = db.connect('apollo.db') #Connecting to the database
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            (username, email, firstName, surname, age, password)) #Inserting the user's data into the table

conn.close() #Closing the connection
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to  `commit()` the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Like pbacterio already answered, you have to commit your changes by calling cursor.commit(), so any actions that were buffered (in another file, if i remember correctly) will be written in your database file.

Answer (score 0):

Also use

```
age= int(age)
```

int(age) returns integer value but you need to store back.